# NSProgress when to remove the observer

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, key-value-observing, nsprogress

NSProgress is a useful class for tracking progress across queues. It relies on observing the "fractionCompleted" property. But when/how are you supposed to remove the observer? I tried dispatch_group and dispatch_barrier but the observer is still removed before all the work has been completed.

This is the code I have so far.

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String!,
    ofObject object: AnyObject!,
    change: [NSObject : AnyObject]!,
    context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
    if keyPath == "fractionCompleted"
    {
        progressBar.doubleValue = (object as NSProgress).fractionCompleted
        println((object as NSProgress).localizedDescription)
    }
    else
    {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}


var overallProgress : NSProgress?
@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject)
{
    overallProgress = NSProgress(totalUnitCount: 100)
    overallProgress?.cancellable = true
    overallProgress?.cancellationHandler = {() -> () in
        println("cancelled")
    }
    overallProgress?.addObserver(self,
        forKeyPath: "fractionCompleted",
        options: (.Initial | .New),
        context: nil)

    var dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create()

    dispatch_group_async(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {


    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) 

  { [unowned self] in

        if !(self.overallProgress?.cancelled ?? false)
        {
            self.overallProgress?.becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount(50)
            self.doWork(2)
            self.overallProgress?.resignCurrent()
        }

        if !(self.overallProgress?.cancelled ?? false)
        {
            self.overallProgress?.becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount(50)
            self.doWork(1)
            self.overallProgress?.resignCurrent()
        }

    }

    dispatch_group_notify(dispatchGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            println("remove")
            self.overallProgress?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "fractionCompleted")
        }
    }

  //    dispatch_barrier_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
 //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
 //println("remove")
 //self.overallProgress?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "fractionCompleted")
 //         }
 //     }
}


@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject)
{
    overallProgress?.cancel()
}


func doWork(sleeptime : UInt32)
{
    let privateProgess = NSProgress(totalUnitCount: 5)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { [unowned self] in
        for index : Int64 in 0...5
        {
            sleep(sleeptime)
            privateProgess.completedUnitCount = index
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The work in `doWork` is not in the same `dispatch_group` as the work you dispatch in `start`. If you want `dispatch_group_notify` to happen after all the work is complete, then `doWork` needs to use `dispatch_group_async` to dispatch that inner work as well. Otherwise, the two calls to `doWork` will return right away, and the only block in the group will then complete, causing your `dispatch_group_notify` block to be executed right away. The easiest approach will likely be to add a parameter to `doWork` to pass in the `dispatch_group_t` so that the inner work can be done as part of that group as well.

Comment: I ended up passing in the dispatch_group_t and using dispatch_group_enter (before starting the work) and dispatch_group_leave (called by the work fund. after completion) to signal the end of a group.